# How to map entity with "self-hierarchical" relationship using a join table in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1, ef-core-2.2

I'm having some trouble with an existing database structure, that I unfortunately can't change.

I have the following tables (abbreviated for simplicity)

```
CREATE TABLE EntityRelationship (
    ChildID int,
    ParentID int
)

CREATE TABLE Entity (
    EntityID varchar,
    EntityRelationshipID int
)
```

I mapped the entities as follows:

```
public class EntityRelationship {
    [ForeignKey("Entity")]
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentEntity")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public Entity ParentEntity { get; set; }
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }
}

public class Entity {
    [Key]
    public String EntityId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentEntity")]
    public int EntityRelationshipId { get; set; }

    public EntityRelationship ParentEntity { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<EntityRelationship>()
    .HasOne(c => c.ChildEntity)
    .WithOne(c => c.ParentEntity);
```

I made sure to eager load the navigational properties at load time, but I'm still getting no results back.

I'm assuming it has to do with my mapping, or maybe because the DB structure, with the join table, isn't by convention with a one-to-one mapping, it trips the whole thing up.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Just for sake of clarity, what I'd like to be able to do is go:

```
Entity parent = db.Entities.First().ParentEntity.Entity;

while (parent.ParentEntity.Entity != null) {
     parent = parent.ParentEntity.Entity;
}
```

so as to find the top-most parent of an entity.

Comment: What are the relationships in the existing database? e.g. `CONSTRAINT FOREGIN KEY …. REFERENCES …`.  `Entity.EntityRelationshipID` definitely should *not* be a FK, but most likely *alternate key*. And most likely the relationship through join table is many-to-many or one-to-many, depending on unique constraints on join table. The correct mapping depends on all these details, so you really need to show all the relevant information about involved db tables.

Comment: Sorry - I should've been more clear about the database. Unfortunately the actual constraints are "wrong" in the database, but it is a legacy monolith DB and we can't change the structure (yes, it's really that bad). However - your alternate key suggestion got the ball rolling for me, and I am able to to load the navigational property for the immediate parent - would you mind making a quick answer that I can accept? I will create a new question in order to figure out how to recursively load parent entities until parent==null Thanks!

Comment: Ok, but parent having a single child doesn't sound logical. Could you clarify if the parent could have many (0..N) children or one (0..1) child?

Comment: Technically the database constraints allow for 0..N, but that is (unfortunately) not the way data is actually used in the database. Luckily in the scenario that I'm mapping the data I'm ONLY interested in the parent, so the child relationships don't really change anything, and I don't need change tracking as I'm only reading data, so there's no danger of messing anything up in the data either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this model, the link entity `EntityRelationship` implies *two* FK relationships represented by the `ChildId` and `ParentId`. For both relationships link entity is the *dependent* and the main entity `Entity` is the *principal* with `EntityRelationshipId` being the *principal key*.

So basically you need to correctly map the keys and navigation properties of these *two* relationships. Remove the `[ForeignKey]` data annotations to not mess around

```
public class Entity
{
    [Key]
    public string EntityId { get; set; }
    public int EntityRelationshipId { get; set; }
    public EntityRelationship ParentEntity { get; set; }
}

public class EntityRelationship
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Entity ParentEntity { get; set; }
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }
}
```

and then use the following fluent configuration (it can be configured from the other side, I've choose the `Entity` because it looks more naturally to me to see the mapping):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>(builder =>
{
    // child => parent
    builder.HasOne(e => e.ParentEntity)
        .WithOne(r => r.Entity)
        .HasForeignKey<EntityRelationship>(r => r.ChildId)
        .HasPrincipalKey<Entity>(e => e.EntityRelationshipId);
    // parent => children
    builder.HasMany<EntityRelationship>()
        .WithOne(r => r.ParentEntity)
        .HasForeignKey(r => r.ParentId)
        .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.EntityRelationshipId);
});
```